# Application of MMP in other branches of algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, minimal-model-program

I'm learning minimal model program (MMP) recently. For a projective variety $X$, following MMP, we can do a sequence of birational transformations making $K_X$ nef or to a Mori fiber space.

My questions are:

1. What are applications of MMP (and abundance) in classical algebraic geometry problems?
2. Does MMP (and abundance) have applications in other branches of algebraic geometry?

Comment: Birkar's proof of boundedness of Fano varieties has been used to construct theoretical bounds in many other contexts. One example can be found in the papers of Brian Lehmann and Sho Tanimoto on the Geometric Manin Conjecture. Another is in the study of Cremona groups (e.g., Blanc-Lamy-Zimmermann recently constructed infinitely many homomorphisms from the Cremona group to $\mathbb{Z}/2$.)

Answer (score 8):

Birational experts on this website will probably give you a more detailed answer, but I think that the "techniques" developped to solve the MMP, rather than the big results, are more likely to have applications in other branches of AG.

In particular, birational geometers have developped quite unrivaled tools to produce rational curves on projective varieties with $-K_X$ positive.

In 1979, Mori used these tools to prove (see [Projective manifolds with ample tangent bundles](https://doi.org/10.2307/1971241)) that, up to isomorphisms, the only smooth projective variety with ample tangent bundle is the projective space. Hwang and Mok used (in the early 2000's) similar ideas to study the variety of minimal rational tangents and prove (global) deformation rigidity of many homogenous spaces (see [Rigidity of irreducible Hermitian symmetric spaces of the compact type under Kähler deformation](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002220050209)). More recently, Ionescu and Russo produced many rational curves on varieties with "quadratic entry loci" to prove an interesting special case of Hartshorne conjecture on complete intersections in projective space (see [Manifolds covered by lines and the Harsthorne conjecture for quadratic manifolds](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23525798)).